# Is it possible to run supervisor restart queue_name programatically in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, supervisord

I have an issue with Laravel jobs. The job is successfully registered but after being fired it does not give proper error message if there is an error. I tried to debug on my computer and that's okay. Then I run supervisor restart queue_name from worker then it works well without any changes in code. So if the error appears again, I want to restart the job but don't want to run the command from the worker. is it possible to run the command from laravel programmatically? like a command in laravel? we can run it from worker with command `php artisan command_name` and also run it from code(`Artisan::call('command_name')`). if that's possible how's the implementation?

Comment: what is your 'QUEUE_DRIVER' ?

Comment: the driver is database